# Printing out Highest Mark and Name of student

Tags: java

So i have to input 10 names and marks into two arrays, and print out the best students name and marks. I am still new to java, i can only print out the max mark from the array, but how am i going to link it to the students name?

```
import java.util.Scanner;                                                                                                                                                                                          
public class storeMarks  {                                                                                                                                                                                         
    public static void main (String[]args){                                                                                                                                                                        

        Scanner tomato = new Scanner(System.in);                                                                                                                                                                   

        double max;                                                                                                                                                                                                
        double marks[];                                                                                                                                                                                            
        marks= new double[10];                                                                                                                                                                                     
        int i;                                                                                                                                                                                                     

        for(i=0; i<10; i++) {                                                                                                                                                                                      
            System.out.println("Enter marks: ");                                                                                                                                                                   
            marks[i]=tomato.nextDouble();                                                                                                                                                                          
        }                                                                                                                                                                                                          
        max = marks[0];                                                                                                                                                                                            
        for(i = 0; i < 10; i++) {                                                                                                                                                                                  
            if(max < marks[i]) {                                                                                                                                                                                   
                max = marks[i];                                                                                                                                                                                    
            }                                                                                                                                                                                                      
        }                                                                                                                                                                                                          
        System.out.println("Highest marks:"+max);                                                                                                                                                                  
    }                                                                                                                                                                                                              
}
```

Comment: Hold onto the index of the max value.

Comment: If you ensure that the index in each array corresponds to a specific individual student, then you could find out which index gives you the max value, and hence retrieve the student name from the other array using the index. I.e. you are ensuring that array position infers information about student identity and corresponding mark.

Comment: ha! i get it now, let me try it out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created a class student:

```
public class Student {

    private double mark;
    private String name;

    public Student()
    {
        mark = 0;
        name = "";
    }

    public Student(int mark, String name)
    {
        this.mark = mark;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public double getMark()
    {
        return mark;
    }
    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setMark(double mark)
    {
        this.mark = mark;
    }

}
```

then I edited your code in main

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here

    ArrayList<Student> studs = new ArrayList<Student>();
    for(int i=0; i< 3; i++)
    {
        studs.add(new Student());
    }

    Scanner tomato = new Scanner(System.in);                                                                                                                                                                   

    double max;                                                                                                                                                                                             
    int i;                                                                                                                                                                                                     

    for(i=0; i<3; i++) {  
         System.out.println("Enter name of student: ");                                                                                                                                                                   
        studs.get(i).setName(tomato.nextLine()); 
        System.out.println("Enter marks: ");                                                                                                                                                                   
        studs.get(i).setMark(tomato.nextDouble()); 
        tomato.nextLine();
    }                         
    int position = 0;
    max = studs.get(0).getMark();                                                                                                                                                                                            
    for(i = 0; i < 3; i++) {                                                                                                                                                                                  
        if(max < studs.get(i).getMark()) {                                                                                                                                                                                   
            max = studs.get(i).getMark(); 
            position = i;
        }                                                                                                                                                                                                      
    }                                                                                                                                                                                                          
    System.out.println("Highest marks:"+studs.get(position).getMark() + " student name " + studs.get(position).getName());
}
```

however, it is not the simplest choice

**Edit: Simplier**

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here


    Scanner tomato = new Scanner(System.in);                                                                                                                                                                   
    double[] marks = new double[10];
    String[] names = new String[10];
    double max;                                                                                                                                                                                             
    int i;                                                                                                                                                                                                     

    for(i=0; i<3; i++) {  
         System.out.println("Enter name of student: ");                                                                                                                                                                   
        names[i] = (tomato.nextLine()); 
        System.out.println("Enter marks: ");                                                                                                                                                                   
        marks[i] = tomato.nextDouble(); 
        tomato.nextLine();
    }                         
    int position = 0;
    max = marks[i];                                                                                                                                                                                            
    for(i = 0; i < 3; i++) {                                                                                                                                                                                  
        if(max < marks[i]) {                                                                                                                                                                                   
            max = marks[i]; 
            position = i;
        }                                                                                                                                                                                                      
    }                                                                                                                                                                                                          
    System.out.println("Highest marks:"+ marks[position] + " student name " + names[position]);
}
```